# PHP file_get_contents on a Google search?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use PHP to return the resultant HTML of a Google search.

So for instance

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com',false);
echo $file;
?>
```

will return the HTML contents of example.com.  The problem is, when I try to do this on a Google search URL, e.g., http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=cats, it returns the HTML from the main Google page and NOT the search results for 'cats'.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a URL of this form:

`http://www.google.com/search?q=cats`

The URL you're using is for their new "instant search"

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've answered my own question.  Sorry.  If I turn Google Insant off, it works fine on a URL like http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cats

Thanks anyway!

Comment: You beat me by 27 seconds :-)